# jUnit testing using hamcrest matcher - how to test the size of a collection.

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, matcher, hamcrest

Does a specific api exist to check the size of collections while unit testing using JUnit/hamcrest.

Currently I am doing -

```
Set<String> result = program.getCollection("inputdata");
assertThat(3, is(result.size()) );
```

Is the above acceptable or I should be using `iterableWithSize` , as below

```
assertThat(result, iterableWithSize(3));
```

What should be the standard way, or are both approaches ok.

Answer (score 3):

The method signature of `assertThat` is:

```
<T> void assertThat(T actual, Matcher<? super T> matcher)
```

Where:

- `actual` is the computed value being compared
- `matcher` is an expression, built of {@link Matcher}s, specifying allowed values

So, it is intended to read something like:

```
assert that this computed value matches that expected value
```

Given this, the assertion in your question:

```
Set<String> result = program.getCollection("inputdata");
assertThat(3, is(result.size()) );
```

Should be expressed as:

```
    assertThat(result.size(), is(3));
```

That's a subtle difference but it is more in keeping with the signature of `assertThat` and the norms of Hamcrest matchers.

The rest of your question deals with whether you should use `is` or `iterableWithSize`. All of the following assertions are (a) functionally equivalent and (b) very readbale (IMHO).

```
assertThat(result.size(), is(3));
assertThat(result, iterableOfSize(3));
assertThat(result, hasSize(3));
```

There is no compelling reason (other than subjective opinion) for choosing one over any of the others. I'd recommend picking one approach and using that consistently since the 'consistency principle' should be favoured over correctness here since they are all ~equally correct.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your approaches are correct, it's just a matter of taste, so you can choose whatever you like the most

Quoting the [iterableWithSize](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIterableWithSize.html) documentation:

> **iterableWithSize(int size)** 
>             Creates a matcher for Iterables that matches when a single pass over the examined Iterable yields an item count that is equal to the specified size argument

I've personally would use simple `assertEquals`:

```
assertEquals(3, result.size());
```

Hamcrest provides a more nature readability, so (I haven't tried it) but I guess you could use:

```
assertThat(result, is(iterableWithSize(3)));
```

Comment: gr8, answers my question. +1.  Right hamcrest provides a more readable style.